# Iterate each value in the first list [] over another list [] to form dictionary {}

Tags: python, python-3.x

Two list as below

**Suits** = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]

**values** = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']

I would like to create a dictionary as below

**Cards** = {"Hearts" : "A", "Hearts": "2", "Hearts" : "3"......}

Each one of the items in **suits** should iterate with all the items in the **values** list. I tried with {}.Fromkeys() but i was not successful.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Not possible. Dict keys are unique in Python. What are you trying to accomplish with such a dict?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a dictionary with the same key appearing multiple times, which is not allowed.

Instead you could have something like:

Cards = {"Hearts" : ['A','2',...,'K'], "Diamonds": ['A','2',...,'K'],......}

And the code for this would be:

```
suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"] 
values = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
cards = {}

for suit in suits:
    cards[suit] = values
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Going through with your wish would result in a dictionary in which one key has multiple values.

If you want a table with all possible combinations of your lists, where you can filter for either 'Suits' or 'values' you could write it into a pandas.DataFrame:

```
Suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
values = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
both = [(onesuit,onevalue) for onesuit in Suits for onevalue in values]

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(both, columns=['Suits', 'values'])
```